# Counter of lines in JTable

Tags: java

In the following code, I browse a table and count lines containing "ble", "cle", "tion"; my counters print the expected values at x=1, but at x=2 and 3 the value of counters is wrong.

I'm working with JTable and trying to count on each value of x the number of lines containing the above strings.

Expected values:
x=1: counter1=5 counter2=5 counter3=6
x=2: counter1=10 counter2=10 counter3=6
x=3: counter1=20 counter2=17 counter3=6

```
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int counter3 = 0;
for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++)
{
  myTable.goToValue(x);               
  for (int i = 0; i < myTable.getRowCount(); i++)
  {    
    if (myTable.getIcon(i, 0).matches("blue.gif"))
    {                                   
      if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 1).contains("ble."))
      {
        counter1++;
      }    
      if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 1).contains("cle."))
      {    
        counter2++;
      }
      if (myTable.getRowValue(i, 1).contains("tion."))
      {
        counter3++;
      }
    }
  }
  System.out.println(counter1);
  System.out.println(counter2);
  System.out.println(counter3);
}
```

Comment: Is this Swing? Are you working with a JTable? Please fill in the necessary details.

Comment: What should the counters be displaying?  What are they displaying?  This question is very unclear.

Comment: Why "tion." and not just "tion"?

Comment: I have updated my questions by taking into account your remarks

Comment: Why "tion." and not just "tion"? it is the same

Comment: @lamisse No. "tion." is not the same as "tion".  Look at the characters inside the quotes.  count them.  look at the last character of the first string.  See?

Comment: yes, but the problem isn't here as I'm seraching for shar ending with .

Comment: What is myTable?  Nowhere in the [core Java API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index-files/index-7.html) is getRowValue or goToValue methods. are you using something special?

Comment: @lamisse: again, if you want good help, you'll need to ask a good question, including providing enough information to allow your question to be answerable. Please read the link, [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), for more on just what information we need.

Answer (score 1):

**Move the initialization of the counter variables inside the for loop.**

You need to reset the values to zero each time through the loop.  The counters just keep counting because you only set them to zero at the beginning of the process, but not before x=2 and x=3.

Change this:

```
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
int counter3 = 0;
for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
    myTable.goToValue(x);
```

To this:

```
for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
    int counter1 = 0;
    int counter2 = 0;
    int counter3 = 0;
    myTable.goToValue(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising `counter1`, `counter2` and `counter3` outside the first `for` loop.

Comment: Peter, I tried to move the initialisation outside the loop but value of counter1couter2and counter3 is wrong when x =2, x=3

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to do here, but if your are counting the number of lines, shouldn't you put

```
 int counter1 = 0;
 int counter2 = 0;
 int counter3 = 0;
```

outside the for loop?

Comment: on each value of x, I count the number of lines containing "ble","cle","tion" , I tried to move the initialisation outside the loop but value of counter is wrong when x =2, x=3

Comment: do the counters for each value of x return the same value?

Comment: the first time , at x=1 , values are correct  but at x=2 and x=3 they continue counting : x=1,counter1=5,counter2=5,counter3=6  x=2,xounter1=10,counter2=10,counter3=12;x=3, counter1=15;counter2=15;counter3=18